# How to bind a NSTableView to a Dictionary declaration or NSDictionaryController?

Tags: cocoa, swift4, nsdictionary, nstableview, xcode10

I'm wondering if I can actually bind the content an NSTableView to an `NSDictionaryController` or a `Dictionary` object, cause I've been reading all kinds of documentation online about how to properly build an `NSTableView` programmatically, but I didn't understand any of those methods.

Can someone show me how to do this in steps?

Comment: Do you want to bind in code or in a StoryBoard/XIB? Do you know how to bind a table view to a `NSArrayController?

Comment: @Willeke I want to bind it in storyboard, and I do not know how to use NSArrayController and NSDictionaryController. Help me lol.

Comment: You can't bind a table to an `NSDictionary` because `NSDictionary` isn't an ordered collection. Tables only work with ordered collections, just as outline views only work with tree collections. Apple has a detailed, step-by-step, [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html) for binding the data in an `NSArray` to an `NSTableView` via an `NSArrayController`.

Comment: Footnote: while you can't bind a table to a dictionary, you can bind a table to an array of dictionaries; I do this all the time. In the individual cell view binding, you can treat each key as a property value. In other words, the binding `objectValue.name` can be a `name` property of some object, or it can be a value in a dictionary with the key "name".

Comment: @JamesBucanek [NSDictionaryController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdictionarycontroller?language=objc) transforms the contents of a dictionary into an array of key-value pairs. You can bind a table view to a dictionary.

Comment: @AgentBilly do you want to bind to one dictionary and show key-value pairs or do you want to bind to an array of dictionaries?

Comment: @Willeke then I stand corrected.